Unable to change fields with the type new ObjectId in Javascript objects
const obj={
  name: 'KA',
  creator: 'qQzMHzU9SPYhdYq2vswQmfeHd4j2',
  default: false,
  _id: new ObjectId('665b1dd655a3a1f154dbb74d'),
  __v: 0
}

I get the above object for mongoose query in js , and I want to convert _id to string
I tried to change it with .toString() method but it doesnot change, but I am able to change other fields
  console.log("Before Change", list);
  list._id = list._id.toString();
  list.name = "XYZ";
  console.log("After Change", list);

Before Change {
  name: 'Hritik',
  creator: 'qQzMHzU9SPYhdYq2vswQmfeHd4j2',
  default: false,
  _id: new ObjectId('665b1dd655a3a1f154dbb74e'),
  __v: 0
}
After Change {
  name: 'XYZ',
  creator: 'qQzMHzU9SPYhdYq2vswQmfeHd4j2',
  default: false,
  _id: new ObjectId('665b1dd655a3a1f154dbb74e'),
  __v: 0
}


are u looking for this

If this is MongDB, please tag it as such

Yes, I am getting the result from mongoDB query, and i have updated the tags accordingly

What are you trying to do with the _id field? You won't be able to save it back to your collection again as a string. Do you just want to convert to string for front-end use?

please try this instead of tostring
 objectId.str


This is also not working , i tried changing the value too but still its the same , as if it's immutable

Mongoose is trying to be clever.
Since you didn't specify an _id field in the schema, Mongoose implicitly added one with the type ObjectId.
When you attempt to set the _id field, mongoose tries to convert the value to match the implicitly specified type.  i.e. when you convert the ObjectId to string, and then assign that string to _id, mongoose notices that it is not the expected type, but it can be converted to the expected type, so it helpfully converts the string to ObjectId for you.
